# Dynkin diagramm of the direct sum of sl(2,c)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L=\underbrace {sl_2(\mathbb C)\oplus...\oplus sl_2(\mathbb C)}_\text{n-summands }$. How does the Dynkin diagram look like?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Dynkin diagram of $L\oplus L'$ is the disjoint union of the diagrams of $L$ and $L'$.

So in your case it will be just $n$ disconnected points.

Comment: But, I have a trouble to understand if $L$ has four roots $\alpha,-\alpha,\beta,-\beta$ then the subalgebra generated by $L_\alpha,L_{-\alpha},L_\beta,L_{-\beta}$ is  $K:=\{[L_\alpha,L_{-\alpha}]\oplus [L_\beta,L_{-\beta}]\}\oplus L_\alpha\oplus L_\beta\oplus L_{-\alpha}\oplus L_{-\beta}$ is this semisimple Lie subalgebra? Is it isomorphic to $sl_2(\mathbb C)\oplus sl_2(\mathbb C)$? Then the Dynkin diagram will be 2 disjoint points?!